# Customize Git Bash Color

Tags: git, color-management

I used to have a `black / orange / green` git bash color style.
Now I needed to download it again and it's a mess (for me).

All pink, lime green and yellow. It hurts my eyes.

Is there a way to return it to old version style or customize it ?

**Edit**
This new version had some great improvement, it allows you to edit font style, transparency and some other things. Really Nice !

But is there a way to edit the text that is your `path` where you are at.

Answer (score 1):

set git to use default colors:

```
$ git config --global color.ui auto
```

alternatively, you can set the colors manually by editing `~/.gitconfig`

```
[color]
  diff = "blue black bold"
  status = "green red"
  branch = red
  interactive = auto
  ui = true
```

you can also set each context manually:

```
[color "status"]
    untracked = cyan
    changed = red
    added = green

[color "branch"]
  current = magenta reverse
  local = magenta
  remote = green
```

quoting [git config documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration#Colors-in-Git):

> You can set the color to any of the following values: normal, black, red, green, yellow, blue, magenta, cyan, or white. If you want an attribute like bold in the previous example, you can choose from bold, dim, ul (underline), blink, and reverse (swap foreground and background)